# creating static-like class or module hierarchy in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a "global" configuration structure for our website's javascript. What I want to be able to do is something like that:

```
company.config.serviceUrl = "http://yoursite.com/servic";
company.config.serviceKey = "123456789ABCDEF";
```

In C# (yes, I am a C# guy), this would be a static class `config`, inside the `company` namespace with a couple of static properties `serviceUrl` and `serviceKey`.

Any idea how I would go about doing this in **TypeScript**? I managed to "do it", but looking at the generated javascript, I am not sure the `Config` class being public is what I want.

Here is the source TypeScript:

```
module company{
    export class Config {
        serviceUrl = "";
        serviceKey = "";
    } 

    export var config = new Config();
}

company.config.serviceUrl = "http://yoursite.com/service";
company.config.serviceKey = "123456789ABCDEF";
```

generated javascript:

```
var company;
(function (company) {
    var Config = (function () {
        function Config() {
            this.serviceUrl = "";
            this.serviceKey = "";
        }
        return Config;
    })();
    company.Config = Config;    
    company.config = new Config();
})(company || (company = {}));
company.config.serviceUrl = "http://yoursite.com/service";
company.config.serviceKey = "123456789ABCDEF";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just use modules:

```
module company.config {
    export var serviceUrl = 'http://...';
    export var serviceKey = '1234567890';
}
```

Alternatively you could use a static on a class if you wanted:

```
module company {
    export class config {
        static serviceUrl = 'http://...';
        static serviceKey = '1234567890';
    }
}
```